# Should I refactor this deeply nested ruby method?

Tags: ruby, rspec, coding-style, format, indentation

Should the following Ruby code be broken into smaller methods or should it be left 'as is' because it would fragment too much if broken up? We are not sure what the right approach should be.
We knew that small methods with individual tests are generally the best practice, however in this case it seems that doing that would spread this code too 'thinly' and greatly reduce readability.  What are the best practices in this area for this type of code?

```
if $?.success?
    puts "Running git fetch"
    `git fetch`
    if $?.success?
        puts "Running git reset --hard origin/#{mbranch}"
        `git reset --hard origin/#{mbranch}`
        if $?.success?
            puts "Running git merge origin/#{branch} --no-ff -m \"STAGED:#{ticket} - #{title}\""
            mergeres=`git merge origin/#{branch} --no-ff -m "STAGED:#{ticket} - #{title}"`
            if $?.success?
               `git log -n 1 | grep "STAGED:#{ticket}"`
               if $?.success?
                  ret=true
                  if resjs eq "yes"
                     puts "Entering reservejs directory..."
                     `cd /#{dir}/zipcar-main/zipcar acs/packages/zipsite/www/reservations/reservejs`
                     if $?.success?
                        puts "Running git fetch on reservejs"
                        `git fetch`
                        if $?.success?
                           puts "Running git checkout master on reservejs"
                           `git checkout master`
                           if $?.success?
                              puts "Running git reset --hard origin/master on reservejs"
                              `git reset --hard origin/master`
                              if $?.success?
                                 puts "Running git merge origin/#{branch} on reservejs"
                                 `git merge origin/#{branch} --no-ff -m "STAGED:#{ticket} - #{title}"`
                                 if $?.success?
                                    `git log -n 1 | grep "STAGED:#{ticket}"`
                                    if $?.success?
                                       b=Dir.chdir("#{firstdir}")
                                       return true
                                    end
                                 end
                              end
                           end
                        end
                     end
                  end
               end
            else
               puts "#{mergeres}"
            end
         end
      end
   end
```

Comment: Yes you really _really_ should.

Comment: This question really should have been posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Your structure screams of needing some iteration.  Instead of a deeply nested conditional, why not an an array of steps, and you just abort processing when a step fails.

```
def do_stuff

  # array of [cmd, output] pairs.
  steps = [
    ["git fetch",                          "Running git fetch"],
    ["git reset --hard origin/#{mbranch}", "Running git reset --hard origin/#{mbranch}"],
    # more steps and feedback labels
  ]

  steps.each do |step|
    cmd, feedback = step # step[0] is the command, step[1] is the feedback
    puts feedback
    return false unless system(cmd).success?
  end
end
```

Or you could use an array of hashes, which even allows you to extend how a "step" is define with as many named keys as you like.

```
steps = [
  {
    cmd: 'git fetch',
    msg: 'Doing a git fetch, hold onto your butts!'
  },
  # more step hashes...
]
```

This makes the linear order of steps much more readable.  And in the future if you have to insert a command in the middle somewhere, you can do so without cursing angrily.

---

And depending on how far you want to go, you could make a `Step` class that encapsulates each step!

```
steps = [
  Step.new(
    cmd: 'git fetch',
    msg: 'Doing a git fetch, hold onto your butts!'
  ),
  # more step instances...
]

steps.each do |step|
  step.run!
  return false if step.failed?
end
```

You could even make each step accept a block in order to run any custom logic around that step.

```
Step.new(
  cmd: 'git fetch',
  msg: 'Doing a git fetch, hold onto your butts!'
) do |result|
  # run some ruby code with result of command before next step
end
```

---

And form that you could make a class that ran collections of steps!

```
runner = StepRunner.new(
  Step.new(
    cmd: 'git fetch',
    msg: 'Doing a git fetch, hold onto your butts!'
  ),
  # more step instances..
)

runner.run!

if runner.success?
  puts 'all steps complete!'
else
  puts "failed with error: #{runner.error}"
end
```

---

But that's getting into overkill zone.  It just depends on how flexible you want this system.  If this is a common pattern, but the steps are varied in type and quantity, you probably want more abstraction.  If this is an isolated occurrence, you can probably make do with somethign on the simpler side.

Comment: I'd recommend reversing the keys and values in `steps` and make it a hash. Keys then become self-documentation for the order of operations. If multiple steps are needed then the value could become an array of commands.

Comment: @theTinMan pre-ruby 1.9, hashes are not ordered, so I don't think this is such a good idea in the case of an older version of ruby installed.

Comment: An array of hashes is probably best of all, so your both right :)

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you could probably make it more readable by collapsing it like:

```
begin
  # do_stuff
end if $?.success?

begin
  # do_stuff
end if $?.success?
```

Alternatively:

```
# do_stuff
return false unless $?.success?
```

Answer (score 1):

In that kind of situation, you should put the condition the other way around, i.e., let it split off whenever the mainstream condition is not satisfied.

Suppose you have the whole procedure within a method `foo`. Then, you can use `return` to escape from the mainstream when a condition is not satisfied.

```
def foo
  return unless $?.success?
  puts "Running git fetch"
  `git fetch`

  return unless $?.success?
  puts "Running git reset --hard origin/#{mbranch}"
  `git reset --hard origin/#{mbranch}`

  return unless $?.success?
  puts "Running git merge origin/#{branch} --no-ff -m \"STAGED:#{ticket} - #{title}\""
  mergeres=`git merge origin/#{branch} --no-ff -m "STAGED:#{ticket} - #{title}"`

  return unless $?.success?
  `git log -n 1 | grep "STAGED:#{ticket}"`

  ...

  return true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Always break down the code to small pieces ALWAYS !! I'm not Ruby ninja, but the maximum nesting level that is "OK" is like 3 levels, after that it is just ugly ugly code.
Better to fragment more than to be with that nesting level for sure. If you need to edit this thing in the future it will be pain in the ass for sure ;]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reproduce large parts of the currently popular answer that show a variety of ways of representing and iterating through a sequence of "steps", let me just suggest the following additional opportunities for enhancing readability and maintainability:

- Recognize that a number of your commands involving outputting the command string itself and provide a mechanism for indicating that rather than having to replicate the string
- Potentially use a variable to represent each command so that you can document the intent of that command in the name. The variable could be an Array or Hash or Proc or some custom class, depending on what approach you are using
- Factor out the control mechanism into a separate method for the sake of modularity